# Contents of .feature file isn't recognized in intelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber, gherkin

I wrote feature files in a project in IntelliJ according to the cucumber syntax. This files worked in another computer. I added the cucumber-java jar files and also installed the Gherkin and cucumber plugins, but still feature files aren't recognized as they should be. 
What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you turn on the plugin for Cucumber/Gherkin?

Comment: yes they are both turned on.

Comment: When you right click a scenario do you have the option to run it?  I'm wondering if perhaps your JUnit is not configured correctly.

Comment: no, I don't have the option to run. what should I do?

Comment: Do the files reside in the source roots?

Comment: I had exactly the same problem. Probably Jetbrains should reconsider recommended plugins for Cucumber!

Comment: Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39131653/intellij-idea-not-recognizing-feature-files). Worked for me. > If you have Substeps IntelliJ Plugin enabled then that might be the issue. you will need to remove and restart.

Answer (score 9):

So i use **IntelliJ 2018**

1) go to Preference
[image]

2)in open tab search "File Types"  and search for text

[image]

3) in Text inside "Registred Patterns" delete "*.feature"

4) then search Cucumber Scenario and add "*.feature"
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Steps I took to get `.feature` files recognized. I know that you've probably done this already, but it might help checking the steps again. If all fails, you could try to reinstall the plugins.

1. Created a new *Java project*
2. Created a new file with the *.feature* extension. Because the plugins were not installed, got the message `"Plugins supporting *.feature files found."` with the option to install the plugins
3. I didn't use this option because the suggested plugins were not what I wanted (check below image):

[image]

4. Instead, I've opened `Settings > Plugins > Browse Repositories` and searched for `Cucumber for Java`
5. When trying to install this plugin you will be required to accept the installation of Gherkin as well. Make sure that after accepting, both plugins are selected.
6. Restart IntelliJ and you should see the feature files recognized:

[image]

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

After installing plugin if you till face problem as i did, my feature files are not getting recognized because of groovy

therefore I manually set

File>>Settings>>Editor>>File Types
click "cucumber Scenario" and Click + to add .Feature in Recognize Patterns.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have `cucumber` for `java` installed, if it is installed follow the below stpes,

1) Create a new feature `file`, like `<test.feature>` , after file creation a dialog box pops up

2) Select cucumber scenario in form the list and click Ok, there you GO.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially two things are required to get cucumber feature recognized as expected type.

1. After adding cucumber-java dependency in pom.xml
2. You have to add Cucumber plugin also from >
   Settings>Plugin>MarketPlace>Search for cucumber for Java and install it

This will also ask you to install Gherkin as a Dependency

Select Yes>> Restart ide

Now you have to change file type from settings >> to cucumber scenario.

Note: you wont be getting Cucumber scenario as recognized type until done above installation.

Select cucumber scenario and Add + wildcard for it as-*.feature